# Universe OCONV argument for zero-padding

Tags: universe, u2

I'm looking for some argument (ARG) such that this code:

```
A = 5
B = OCONV(A,'ARG5')
PRINT B
```

will print to the screen

```
00005
```

Anybody know something which will do this for me?

Answer (score 3):

In Universe I would use the MR% conversion code. Just be aware that it will truncate anything longer than 5 characters.

```
A = 5
B = OCONV(A,'MR%5')
PRINT B
```

I use this a lot when I need to use EVAL in a conditional or as an aggregate function in a SQL or other TCL statement like to find the record with the most fields in a file.

```
SELECT MAX(EVAL "DCOUNT(@RECORD,@FM)") FROM VOC;
SELECT MAX(EVAL "OCONV(DCOUNT(@RECORD,@FM),'MR%8')") FROM VOC;
```

Masking aside these generally return 2 different values on our system.

Comment: I've used PRINT VALUE"R%5" before but it wasn't obvious to me that there was a OCONV version of it, good one.

Answer (score 0):

I am using UniData, but looking at the commands reference manual I can't see anything quite right, in terms of one simple argument to OCONV, or similar. I came up with these (somewhat kludgy) alternatives, though:

`NUMLEN=5
VALUE=5
PRINT CHANGE(SPACES(NUMLEN-LEN(VALUE))," ","0"):VALUE`

Here you are using the `SPACES` function to create that amount of space characters and then convert them to zeros.

`PRINT OCONV(VALUE,"MR":NUMLEN:"(#####)")`

This is using `OCONV` but has to define a string with the "mask" to only shew the final 5 digits. So if NUMLEN changes then the mask string definition would have to change.

`PRINT OCONV(VALUE,"MR":NUMLEN)[3,NUMLEN]`

This version uses `OCONV` but prints starting at the 3rd character and shews the next NUMLEN characters, therefore trimming off the initial "0." that is made by using the "MR" parameter

Answer (score 0):

`PADDED.VALUE = VALUE 'R%5'` is the simplest way to do this.